# iOS Core Plot CPTAxisLabel alignment to CPTPlot

Tags: ios, core-plot

Please look at this image below. I have attached file. My problem with `CPTAxisLabel` labels. They are placed under the tick, but they are not placed under the `CPTPlot` as I want.

How can I add left offset to this labels? I need that my labels will be placed middle the `CPTPlot` object.

[image]

(UPDATED:)

```
-(void)configureGraph
{

    NSInteger max = 0;
    for (NSNumber *number in self.values) {
        NSInteger num = [number integerValue];
        if (num > max) {
            max = num;
        }
    }

    CPTGraph *graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];

    graph.plotAreaFrame.masksToBorder = NO;

    self.hostedGraph = graph;

    graph.paddingBottom = 80.0f;
    graph.paddingLeft  = 0.0f;
    graph.paddingTop    = 50.0f;
    graph.paddingRight  = 0.0f;

    CGFloat xMin = -0.5f;
    CGFloat xMax = [self.titles count];
    if (xMax < 7.0) {
        xMax = 7.0;
    }
    CGFloat yMin = 0.0f;
    CGFloat yMax = max + 25;

    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(xMin) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(xMax)];
    plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(yMin) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(yMax)];

    //graph.backgroundColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
    //graph.plotAreaFrame.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor redColor]];

}

-(void)configurePlots
{    
    CPTBarPlot *plot = [[CPTBarPlot alloc] init];
    //plot.barOffset = CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.30);
    plot.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:190.0f/255.0f green:203.0f/255.0f blue:103.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0]];
    //plot.barWidth = CPTDecimalFromDouble(0.75);
    plot.lineStyle = nil;
    plot.barCornerRadius = 1.0;
    plot.dataSource = self;
    plot.delegate = self;

    CPTGraph *graph = self.hostedGraph;
    [graph addPlot:plot toPlotSpace:graph.defaultPlotSpace];

}

#pragma mark - CPTPlotDataSource methods
-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot {
    return [self.titles count];
}

-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    if ((fieldEnum == CPTBarPlotFieldBarTip) && (index < [self.titles count])) {
            return [self.values objectAtIndex:index];
    }
    return [NSDecimalNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:index];
}

-(CPTLayer *)dataLabelForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)idx
{

    plot.labelOffset = 0;

    CPTMutableTextStyle *style = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    style.color = [[CPTColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:1];
    style.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
    style.fontSize = 12.0f;

    NSString *valueString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.values objectAtIndex:idx]];

    return [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:valueString style:style];
}

- (void)configureAxes
{

    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *) self.hostedGraph.axisSet;
    axisSet.xAxis.hidden = YES;
    axisSet.yAxis.hidden = YES;

    CPTMutableTextStyle *style = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    style.color = [[CPTColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:1];
    style.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
    style.fontSize = 12.0f;

    NSMutableArray *labels = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];
    int idx =0;
    for (NSString *string in self.titles)
    {
        CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:string textStyle:style];
        label.rotation = M_PI/2;
        label.tickLocation = CPTDecimalFromInt(idx);
        label.offset = 10.0f;
        [labels addObject:label];
        idx+=1;
    }

    axisSet.xAxis.axisLabels = [NSSet setWithArray:labels];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either set the `barOffset` to zero (0) and make the bar locations the same as the tick locations or adjust the bar locations returned by the datasource to account for the `barOffset`.

Comment: hello, thanks for your answer, can you describe more, how to make this. because i am new in core plot

Comment: Since there are lots of options here, add some more info to your question to help us answer more clearly based on your situation. Show how the plot is configured, what values are provided by the datasource, where the labels are, etc.

Comment: I have made a little work around when set xMin = -0.5f; not sure if is it correct but to works.

Comment: That's a good way to keep the first bar inside the plot area so it doesn't get cut off.

Answer (score 0):

The CPTAxis class has a property labelOffset which, according to the documentation, is "The offset distance between the tick marks and labels. "

There are a lot of ways to custom labeling from the CPTAxis class, you should check :
https://core-plot.googlecode.com/hg-history/efa73ee50d8edfd0e1d4294cf4bd2c07d9f8af77/documentation/html/iOS/interface_c_p_t_axis.html