# How to set x axis values as string in core plot Bar graph?

Tags: ios, core-plot

I am using the core plot library for implementing bar graph. Right now I facing one problem regarding x axis label values these are by default shown in number. Now I want to set string on it, I tried by making **labelingpolicy** none for x axis labels and added custom labels using

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 3; i++)
 {
    CPTAxisLabel *newLabel = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:@"abcd" textStyle:x.labelTextStyle];
    newLabel.offset       = x.labelOffset +10;
    newLabel.rotation     = M_PI_4;
    [customLabels addObject:newLabel];
}
```

I desired output shouuld be like the image shown below.

[image: On x axis string are shown that I want to show.]

I searched in core plot documentation but unable to got any hint also checked **DatePLot** example but still no luck.
Any help will be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you need to implement data source for the plot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15681070/ios-core-plot-cptaxislabel-alignment-to-cptplot

Comment: Yes thanks. Thats what I want to do.:)