# Core Plot Graphs - y-axis values as strings

Tags: ios, core-plot

I want to set strings for the y-axis instead of numbers. I found this thread,

[iOS Core Plot CPTAxisLabel alignment to CPTPlot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15681070/ios-core-plot-cptaxislabel-alignment-to-cptplot)

I've tried to implement the corresponding version of his code to my y-axis instead, but without success.

Is it possible to use strings instead of numbers on the y-axis?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I had to set the labelingPolicy to none (line 2 in my code below),

```
CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
y.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;

CPTMutableTextStyle *style = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
style.color = [[CPTColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:1];
style.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
style.fontSize = 10.0f;

NSMutableArray *test = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Zero", @"One", @"Two", @"Three", @"Four", nil];

NSMutableArray *labels = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:4];

int index = 0;
for (NSString *string in test)
{
    CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:string textStyle:style];
    label.tickLocation = CPTDecimalFromInt(index);
    label.offset = 5.0f;
    [labels addObject:label];
    index++;
}

axisSet.yAxis.axisLabels = [NSSet setWithArray:labels];
```